# Java "this" Keyword Impact on Code

Tags: java, netbeans, drop-down-menu, this, keyword

So I've been writing code for a while using Netbeans, and the fastest way that I noticed that I could get a dropdown menu for variables and subroutines was using the `this` keyword(when I was new) and ever since it has become a habit.(I am aware of Ctrl + Space) I was curious of how `this` actually affects performance of a program when used for every variable name. Also, from what I've heard some programmers like the `this` keyword because it seems to be easier on the eyes sometimes.

[image: this:]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes no difference performance wise as it compiles to the same bytecode.

However, IMHO, it does reduce readability by cluttering the code.

Note that with `CTRL+SPACE` you can auto-complete the class variable names without having to type `this`.

Comment: Fully agree. In Eclipse there is a Save Action which automatically adds the "this" modifier to all fields. Maybe Netbeans also offers this (!) type of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer it when I read code that uses "this" to reference instance variables.

What if you have a class that is over 200 lines long?

You'd be constantly checking where the variable was defined.

Comment: a variable is accessed within a method. And it can only be an argument of the method, a local variable or an instance (this) variable. Unless your method is 200 lines long (which would scream for refactoring) it should be fairly simple to see if the variable is a parameter or local. And if it is not then you have your answer...

Comment: Still, I believe it makes the code more readable. You can instantly see the scope of the variable without even having to look at the methods params.

Comment: My IDE is good at using different colours for different types of variables so it has never been an issue for me, but in the end it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

> I was curious of how this actually affects performance of a program when used for every variable name.

It has no performance advantage or disadvantage.

> Also, from what I've heard some programmers like the this keyword because it seems to be easier on the eyes sometimes.

It is debatable.  So programmers think it makes code easier to read.  Other programmers think it makes code harder to read.  You need to make up your own mind on that ... maybe in conjunction with other coders who you work with.

(I'm ambivalent.  I use the Eclipse IDE, and Eclipse syntax highlighting makes it easy to ignore the clutter of (technically) unnecessary `this` keywords.)